# After execution action: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

trying to create an action in redux to DELETE my item. I understand that actions must have a defined type so not sure why I am getting this error

Tried looking for similar posts but none of them provide the answer that I need:

./types

`export const DELETE_TASK = 'DELETE_TASK';`

./actions

`import {DELETE_TASK} from './types'`

`` export const deleteTask = id => dispatch => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/tasks/${id}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_TASK,
        payload: id
      })
    )
    .catch(err => 
      dispatch({
        type: console.log(err)
      }))
} ``

./reducers

`case DELETE_TASK:
  return {
    ...state,
    tasks: state.dates.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload)
  };`

./component

`onDeleteTask = id => {
  this.props.deleteTask(id)
}`

`<button onClick={this.onDeleteTask.bind(this, e.id)}>delete task</button>`

I have to mention after the error when I refresh the page item was delete! Action work but I don't understand why this error occurs before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code has an error

```
.catch(err => 
  dispatch({
    type: console.log(err)
  }))
```

`console.log()` always returns `undefined`. So you're dispatching an action `{type: undefined}`. May be you need something like this

```
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
  dispatch({
    type: ERROR
  })
})
```

given that you've defined `ERROR` constant.